# Butterknife+kotlin: Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-android-extensions, butterknife

I am developing an Android project in Kotlin.

My Gradle version 3.5.3

In my app module build.gradle I added Butterknife dependency:

```
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0"
kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0"
```

But I get kotlin compiler warning:

[image]

```
w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).
```

In my app `build.gradle` file I have:

```
  android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
  }
```

Why is above warning? How can I solve it?

(I also tried adding `kapt.incremental.apt=true` in *gradle.peroperties*. It doesn't help.)

Answer (score 1):

Incremental annotation processing must be supported by an annotation processor itself, so you can't do much with the warning. You can try looking into the processor's repository and ask its maintainers about the ETA of incremental annotation processing support.

Update: I've just noticed that butterknife supports incremental processing, so the issue isn't related to the library. The other assumption that there is a problem with kapt. This article might be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@daniel_novak/making-incremental-kapt-work-speed-up-your-kotlin-projects-539db1a771cf

Answer (score 0):

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

add this to below android in app.gradle file

Comment: Let me know if this fixed your issue

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have this in app gradle file, I will update my question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

download JDK11 and
add this line to your bash profile.

```
export JAVA_HOME = /users/JDK11/Contents/Home
```

JDK11 is the folder where your newly downloaded JDK is